# Difficulty simplifying $1/(x^2 + x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3 + x + 1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am having trouble simplifying $1/(x^2 + x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3 + x + 1)$. From my understanding, this means simplifying $1/(x^2 + x)$ to a polynomial of degree less than $deg(x^3 + x + 1) = 3$. My strategy was to express $1/(x^2 + x)$ as some multiple of $x^{-1}$, and then if I could determine a representation of $x^{-1}$ that was a polynomial, I would be good to go. I was able to express $1/(x^2 + x)$ as $(x^{-1})^4$. However, I am having difficulty finding a representation of $x^{-1}$ that is a polynomial. Below is what I have so far:

$$x^2 + x = (x + 1)x = x^3x = x^4\\1/(x^2 + x) = x^{-4} = (x^{-1})^4$$

Comment: Just apply the Euclidean algorithm

Comment: @LukasHeger Could you elaborate on how I could use the Euclidean Algorithm here?

Comment: $x^3+x+1=(x^2+x)(x-1)+(2x+1)$

Comment: lhf got it. $x^3+x$ is divisible by both $x$ and $x+1$, hence by $x^2+x$. That is oe quick way to get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

We apply the Euclidean algorithm (really it's just one division with remainder here) in $\Bbb F_2[x]$:

$$x^3+x+1+x(x^2+x)=x^2+x+1=(x^2+x)+1$$ so
$$1=(x^3+x+1)+(x+1)(x^2+x)$$
Reducing this mod $(x^3+x+1)$ yields $1\equiv (x+1)(x^2+x)$ so the inverse is just $(x+1)$.

Note that this approach is a general method to compute the inverse of $g \in k[x]$ in $k[x]/(f)$ for some field $k$ (assuming that the inverse exists and hence $\gcd(f,g)=1$): the Euclidean algorithm yields $a,b \in k[x]$ such that $1=\gcd(f,g)=af+bg$. Then reducing this equation shows that $b$ is an inverse of $g$ mod $f$.

Comment: Couldn't the inverse of $x$ also be computed from $x^3 + x + 1 = 0$, which means that $1 = x^3 + x$ and thus $x^{-1} = x^2 + 1$?